# Does Apple’s Hide my Email feature really work?

Tags: email, apple, deanonymization

I was wondering if when you use something like Apple's 'Hide my Email' functionality if there's some way for the organization to still recover the user's original email if the user is then asked to confirm their email (eg you get a confirmation email that asks you to click a link)?

More specifically, is there some information communicated when you click the link to confirm that could point back to your actual email in any direct way? I’m sure there’s probably several indirect ways, like maybe associating a given IP address with a users email or something, but I’m more interested in the interaction in a semi-isolated environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide my Email is basically creating a mail alias. As long as you choose this alias as sender in E-mail communication with the site it will hide your original address.

But if you deliberately or unintentionally use your "main" address then the recipient will see this. This means that E-mail client you use has to be aware of the feature, so that it uses the address where you received the mail as sender for a reply instead of your main address. While this is probably integrated into mail clients from Apple itself, you cannot expect it from some arbitrary E-mail program.

> ...  like maybe associating a given IP address with a users email or something,

E-mail addresses have no relation to IP addresses. The same E-mail address can be used from multiple IP addresses and multiple E-mail addresses can be used from the same IP.

But, if a recipient has multiple E-mails from you, where some have the mail address alias and some your main address, then they might try to associate  these mails with each other to find out what might come from the same sender. But this requires them to have mails with your original address as sender in the first place.

Comment: Back in the old days when people all used local email clients (instead of a web page) to send emails, the IP of the mail client would be included in the headers. I think some big email operators now omit this for privacy, but most private operations wouldn't have such scrubbing.

Comment: When you say the client needs to be aware of the alias, do you mean just for if you’re actually sending an email or also if you’re clicking a link associated with the email, like those emails they send with links to confirm the email?

Comment: @JustinT: this is only about sending emails, not clicking links.

Comment: Thanks! So what I am wondering is whether there’s any info that you communicate when clicking that link that could be a potential privacy vulnerability; does it essentially just tell the service that for a given email/ account that its verified, or is it sending other kind of information as well?

Comment: @JustinT: A link for confirming a mail address is just a link - nothing magical. You would probably not expect an arbitrary link to retrieve your email addresses from somewhere on your system - and similar such confirmation links do not have this capability either.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks!